# Does anyone know how to do flow layout using RecyclerView?

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview, flowlayout

Does anyone know how to do flow layout using RecyclerView?

How to change span count dynamically?

[Answer :](https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager)

[image: Like this]

Comment: Can you please explain in detail ?

Comment: i want design like in above picture, i think this can be achieved by recycler-view but don't know how to do it

Comment: https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout this may help you.

Comment: Thankyou  @DhinakaranThennarasu

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this? All the libraries that are out there, are just adding views to the ViewGroup, no recycling is involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full example 
of using **custom Library** which acts like List [GitHubLibrary TagLayout](https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout)

- **Sample Code**:-

`mFlowLayout.setAdapter(new TagAdapter<String>(mVals)
   {
       @Override
       public View getView(FlowLayout parent, int position, String s)
       {
           TextView tv = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tv,
                   mFlowLayout, false);
           tv.setText(s);
           return tv;
       }
   });`

**Using below code you can pre set selection you wanted:**-

```
mAdapter.setSelectedList(1,3,5,7,8,9);
```

**Will show result like below:-**

[image]

Comment: how can I add multiple sections of tags? I want to do it dynamically

Answer (score 6):

Best solution is to use a RecyclerView with google FlexLayoutManager

```
// Set layout manager
    val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutManager

// Now you can add your normal recyclerview adapter

recyclerview.adapter = MyListAdapter(list)
```

Add below dependency in your build.gradle file

```
 implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:3.0.0'
```

This will work like a charm.

Comment: saved my day... easiest solution

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, kudos!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout) and put it as a child of ScrollView.
Samples for flow layout are available in repository.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:minHeight="50dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button" />
        </com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello world" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Also you can add or remove views programatically using following methods given in sample.

```html
 public void addItem(View view) {

        int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_blue_dark);

        View newView = new View(this);
        newView.setBackgroundColor(color);

        FlowLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        params.rightMargin = 10;
        newView.setLayoutParams(params);

        mFlowLayout.addView(newView);
    }

    public void removeItem(View view) {

        mFlowLayout.removeView(getLastView());

    }

    public void toggleItem(View view) {

        View last = getLastView();

        if(last.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            last.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            last.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private View getLastView() {
        return mFlowLayout.getChildAt(mFlowLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
    }
```